# remove parent div leaving its child div

Tags: javascript

I have child div inside its parent.

How to remove parent div leaving only its child untouched?

I don't use jQuery.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

to become

```
<div id="child"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the element, get its parentNode, replace it with the child.

```js
var child = document.getElementById('child');
child.parentNode.replaceWith(child);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    A
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have support issues with `replaceWith` you can try the `insertBefore` approach.

```js
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var parent = child.parentNode;

parent.parentNode.insertBefore(child, parent);
parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    A
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly on Windows/Mac, however on Android  from time to time it still shows removed parent div.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=replaceWith  there are potential browser coverage issues.

Comment: So, there is no other way to approach this task with crossbrowser capability?

Comment: @Serg Added another approach using `insertBefore` which has larger browser support.